# if else statement inside while loop.(i m trying to insert a node at a given position in linked list.)

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, linked-list, infinite-loop

```
void insertM(struct node **s,int pos,int n)
   {    
   struct node *temp,*e;
   temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   temp->x=n;
   temp->link=NULL;
   int count=1;
   e=*s;
   while(e!=NULL)
   {
       if(count==pos)
       {
           temp->link=e->link;
           e->link=temp;
       }          
       else
       {
           e=e->link;
           count++;
       }

   }
}
```

If I remove the above else statement and put its content in the while loop after the if statement, the program works. But with the else statement it doesn't work. Why? What's wrong with the else statement?

Comment: Use a debugger to single-step through the code. It's a pretty obvious error.

Comment: I m sorry but I m new at this.Can you please explain the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you need to find a debugger appropriate for your platform, read about how to use it, then run your program under said debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when `count==pos` gets `true` you have an infinite loop because you don't change `e` and `count` anymore. In other words, the execution will constantly take the TRUE-path of the if-statement and go on forever.

You should add a `break` statement - like:

```
   if(count==pos)
   {
       temp->link=e->link;
       e->link=temp;

       break;  // Break out of the while-loop as we are done
   }
```

The reason your code worked without the else-part is that `count` and `e` was changed in every loop. So sooner or later you reached the end of the list and the loop terminated.

However, for performance it is better to use the `break`statement.

Also notice that your code has a bug when called with `pos` equal 1. You need to handle that as a special case and update `*s`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the else statement is causing an error is because when you finally find the target, `count` doesn't increment. Therefore, `count` will always equal `pos` and the loop never breaks. To better visualize this error, imagine trying to add a node at the first node starting at the while loop,

```
e is not null so loop body is executed
count == pos evaluates to true so temp is inserted after e
else statement gets skipped so count stays at 1 and e stays at the first node
e is not null so loop body is executed
count == pos evaluates to true so temp is inserted after e
```

As you can see, you're constantly adding `temp` after the front infinitely many times because `count` is never changing when you find the target node. To better understand these errors in the future, use a debugger.